# Redirect one file from http to https

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect one file from http to https using .htaccess but it is not working. The strange thing is if I add / at the end of the url it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^offers\.html/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/offers.html [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact URL you are trying to rewrite?

Comment: Test with curl to avoid issues with browser caches.

Comment: Unless you have additional directives in your `.htaccess` file then a caching issue is highly probable (301 redirects are cached hard by the browser by default). (_Aside:_ Slashes at the end of `.html` files, ie. additional pathname information, would normally result in a server generated 404, unless you have specifically enabled this - which suggests you do have more directives _somewhere_?)

Comment: @Stefan I didn't think of using curl for testing redirects, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Actually it was more of a some server related issue and my web hosting provider fixed the issue. There is nothing wrong with the code above and it's working as expected.Thanks everyone for trying to help.